# Multiples Values in 1 column python pandas

Tags: pandas, jupyter

I have this dataframe

```
   CRIM ZN INDUS CHAS NOX RM AGE DIS RAD TAX PTRADIO B-1000 LSTAT MEDV
0   0.00632 18.00 2.310 0 0.5380 6.5750 65... (14 values for each row, but this is 1 column)
1   0.02731 0.00 7.070 0 0.4690 6.4210 78...
2   0.02729 0.00 7.070 0 0.4690 7.1850 61...
3   0.03237 0.00 2.180 0 0.4580 6.9980 45...
4   0.06905 0.00 2.180 0 0.4580 7.1470 54...
... ...
501 0.06263 0.00 11.930 0 0.5730 6.5930 69...
502 0.04527 0.00 11.930 0 0.5730 6.1200 76...
503 0.06076 0.00 11.930 0 0.5730 6.9760 91...
504 0.10959 0.00 11.930 0 0.5730 6.7940 89...
505 0.04741 0.00 11.930 0 0.5730 6.0300 80...
506 rows × 1 columns
```

How do I turn this data frame to 506 rows x 14 columns?
I'm new to programming so sorry if my question is easy to solve
I'm using python jupyter and pandas
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for how you got this dataframe? Did you read it from a file?

Comment: Yes, i read it from a csv file, which I cant' manipulate outside of jupyter

Comment: Then try to set the space character as the separation character when you do that, e.g. `df = pandas.read_csv(..., sep=' ')`.

Comment: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 31 fields in line 42, saw 32.
I got this error. There is 1 space before the first value and there are 2 spaces between the rest of the values. I got this dataset from this website https://www.kaggle.com/vikrishnan/boston-house-prices. I'm learning machine learning and I'm trying to practice

Comment: I just solved it. I used 'raw_data = pd.read_csv('housing.csv', delim_whitespace=True)'. Thanks for the help, Arne